# App Service folder access in Azure with ftp

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-web-app-service

I have an app Service in Azure that contains folders and files.

Via FileZilla I can reach the file structure. I have a 3rd party vendor that needs to upload files to a specific folder.

I can create an ftp with access to all content on the app service. But is it possible to limit the users access to only one folder or a specific drive that my app service can reach? Ideally a subfolder under wwwroot\content.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Though, this is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mount file share from Azure Storage to AppService via mapping and let the users access only files via File Shares not App Service.

Comment: Thank you @Kamil. I created a file share and mapped it to the AppService via the Service Connector. This works great for me.

Answer (score -1):

if your service plan is linux, you can log via ssh and set file/folder permissions manually.

But remember, the day when you make a new deploy/update in your application hosted on a cloud server, you probably will lose your files.
You need to use a separated environment for acess/management of storage, that will be independent where you application is hosted and running.